# Android Maps: My Location Button doesn't work on activity first launch

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

When I run my Maps activity and accept the location permissions for the first time, if I press on "My Location" button nothing happens.

However, if i close the activity and go back to it, the button works fine after that! So, The problem is only after I accept the permissions for the first time of activity launch.

If I recreate the activity after accepting permissions the problem is solved, but I do not like that solution, plus I want to understand the cause of the problem.

What is causing this bug?

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements` OnMapReadyCallback {

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
        options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        mapFragment.newInstance(options);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
```

#

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            requestLocationPermissions();
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
    }
```

#

```
 public void requestLocationPermissions() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    15);
        }else{

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);//needs location permission
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        }
    }
```

```
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 15) {
            if (grantResults.length == 0) {
                requestLocationPermissions();
            } else {
                if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || grantResults[1] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  ) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You have to accept all Permissions!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Permission refused","Permission refused");
                    requestLocationPermissions();
                } else {
                    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                   }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: after accepting the location permission, refresh your current activity without an animation , hope its help you

Comment: @Sniffer Ok, if I reCreate() the activity, the problem is solved. But, I don't like this solution, plus I still do not know the cause of the problem.

Comment: Please open your google maps android application first, then after open your applications. If it works as excepted then please let me know.(Make sure your GPS is turned on)

Comment: @MohitGaur
1) Deleted my app.
2) GPS is ON, I opened google maps app, saw my current location active.
3) installed my app, accepted permissions.
Same problem...

Comment: no, don't delete it, just open google maps before opening your app

Comment: I am having exactly same issue, do you have found the cause ?

Comment: @forlayo Nope. If u happen to find a solution, please leave a comment.

Comment: @Mena posted whay I do as a workaround without reloading the activity :). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code to check what values from latitude and longitude you receive when you first grant the permission. The location might not be set at that moment. If the GPS is not already turned on, acquiring fine location takes sometimes a little more time. I've had the same issue on some of the devices used for testing.

Comment: GPS is ON.
Location is correct when I grant permission.
Even if I wait for a while, the location button doesn't do anything except after I recreate the activity

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this issue and at the minute the only workaround I've found is to use the [fuse location client](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) to retrieve the location of the device and add a custom behavior for "my location" button.

In this way it works all times without reloading the activity.

```
private void getDeviceLocation() {
        /*
         * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
         * cases when a location is not available.
         */
        try {
            if (hasLocationPermission()) {
                fusedLocationClient
                        .getLastLocation()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                                if (location != null) {
                                    lastLocation = location;
                                    // Logic to handle location object
                                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                                                    location.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                                    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(MapsActivity.this);
                                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                                    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                                } else {
                                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                                    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

MapsActivity is a listener of GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener and then have this code

```
@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    // I've tried just setting the default behavior of the button, but just works after reloading
    // the activity, then I've managed the click event to latest location; now it works for
    // all cases.
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(),
                    lastLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
    return false;
}
```

This is the code of onMapReady

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    getMuseums();

    if (!hasLocationPermission()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        return;
    }
    getDeviceLocation();
}
```

And my actual DEFAULT_ZOOM value is 10.